# How to create a pop up(asking for sign up) in the home page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

I want to create a pop up in the home page of my site when each time a new visitor visits the site. I have the pop up window. The problem is whenever I hit on home page it comes. I want it to display only once in the home page not each time I click for home page during the visit to the site. If the browser is closed or the session is out, it pop-up coming is fine.

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

What about 'is_new_visitor' of Visitor data:

```
$visitorData = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData();
```

Locally it is not resulting any values? Any other suggestions!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

the easiest approach would be to set the session variable directly in your pop-up block (if you have the Block layer for it). It needs to be set after the block is actually displayed (so it will be displayed the 1st time) - for example in the block destructor:

```
public function __destruct() {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setOldVisitor(true);
}
```

Then before you show the pop-up add the case:

```
if (!Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getOldVisitor()) {
    //do your thing here
}
```